# Classification of Singularities of the function

Tags: complex-analysis

What about the singularities of the function $$\frac{1}{\sin z}$$ I know that at z=$n\pi$, there is singularity, but what about its classification.

Answer (score 2):

Since

$$\lim_{z\to n\pi}\left(z-n\pi\right)\frac1{\sin z}=\frac1{\cos n\pi}=(-1)^n\neq 0\;\;,\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb Z$$

all the sigularities are simple poles with the above residue.

Comment: So, are there any other poles then, what does $(-1)^n\neq 0$ implies....

Comment: It implies the points $\;z_n=n\pi\;$ are *simple* poles of the functions, by definition. And no, there are no other points since the denominator function doesn't vanish anywhere else and is thus an analytic function anywhere else.

Comment: Well,Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick, informal, calculation-free approach.  You probably know already that $\sin z$ has no zeros except for its real zeros at $z=n\pi$.  If you draw, or just mentally visualise, the graph of $y=\sin x$, you will see that it crosses straight over the axis at these points.  (By "straight over" I mean it doesn't "bounce back" like $x^2$ at the origin, and it doesn't "wiggle" like $x^3$ at the origin.)  Therefore $\sin z$ has simple zeros (zeros of order $1$) at these points, and its reciprocal $1/\sin z$ has simple poles (poles of order $1$) at these points.

Answer (score 1):

Since, for $z\neq n \pi$, $n=\pm 1,\pm2,\pm3,\ldots$, we have (see [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.22))
$$
\displaystyle \sin z = z \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 - \frac{z^2}{(n\pi)^2} \right)
$$
then
$\displaystyle z \to
\frac{1}{\sin z}
$
is analytic everywhere except at $z=n \pi$, $n=\pm 1,\pm2,\pm3,\ldots$,where it has **simple poles**.

Comment: So, are there any other poles then ?

Comment: @RoshanShrestha No, these are the **only** poles. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please tell me how many types of singularities are there ?

Comment: @RoshanShrestha Yes, there is only one type of singularities : 'simple poles'. Hoping to be clear.